# WPF textBlock expansion inside a layout

Tags: wpf, layout, textblock

I have the following XAML code:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TileViewDT">
        <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel Height="40.5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock x:Name="Name" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Width="132" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Size" Foreground="DarkGray" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=@Size}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Image x:Name="Img" Source="BtnImg/Computer.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10,0,5,0" Width="48" Height="48"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**Output:**

[image]

I'm trying to get the same look of Windows Explorer as much as possible, So I want to keep both of the TextBlocks "Name" and "Size" in the center when the text is short and when the name text's length is longer than the item space it goes up (by 1 line maybe) to get this look :

[image]

So how would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in Stackpanel instead of setting Height you should set MaxHeight and VerticalAlignment property value should be Center instead of Bottom and that should do your work:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TileViewDT">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel MaxHeight="40.5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="5,2,5,2" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Name" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=@Name}" Width="132" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Size" Foreground="DarkGray" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=@Size}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Image x:Name="Img" Source="BtnImg/Computer.png" Stretch="Fill" Margin="10,0,5,0" Width="48" Height="48"/>
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Hope it works !!!

Comment: one more question, when the textBlock has 2 lines how to decrease the space between the first line and the second?

Comment: Set TextBlock LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" and LineHeight property to whatever value you want.